# Add scroll bar to browser if iframe get overflow with content

Tags: asp.net

I'm using Iframe in asp.net applicaiton.
I'm using Radmenustrip. When user click one of the tab,I'll load corresponding page in Iframe.
here I want to add scroll bar to the browser not in iframe when content is not fit into the iframe.
By default I gave 100% height.
i tried with 
html{overflow-y:scroll}
but its not working..
here is my code

```
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">    
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            background-image: url('images/BG_Gradient.JPG');
            width:90%;          
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position:center; 
        }         
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
   <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server"/>  
  <div id="right">
  <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  
        style="height:58px;margin-top:0px;">
        <tr>
            <td width="9%" height="100%" style="padding-left:0px" colspan="2">
            <asp:Image id="imgHeader" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl="~/images/Banner.gif" ImageAlign="Middle" Width="100%"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
      <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="menuStrip" runat="server" CssClass="TabStrip1"   
            MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1" ClickSelectedTab="True" 
          UnSelectChildren="True" style="margin-left:9.5px;border-left-style:none;" 
            Width="98.5%" ShowBaseLine="True" 
            EnableEmbeddedSkins="False" Skin="Office2007" OnClientTabSelecting="OnClientTabSelecting" 
            OnClientTabSelected="OnClientTabSelected">
           <Tabs>
           <telerik:RadTab Text="Tab1"  NavigateUrl="Tab1.aspx" 
                   CssClass="Tab1" Target="framebody">
             </telerik:RadTab>  
            </Tabs>            
    </telerik:RadTabStrip>
   <iframe id="framebody" name="framebody"   runat="server"  scrolling="no"
            frameborder="0">  
    </iframe>
   </div>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_TabIndex" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

pls help me asap.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to size an iframe to its content, you must query the IFrame contentDocument for its height. If the content is not from your domain, this becomes a challenge.

Comment: Hi Im trying to get the iframe contentdocument height in Tab1.aspx page,but its giving value like 443 px, not giving exactly.i'm doing like var frame = window.frameElement; frame.style.height=frame .contentwindow.document.body.scrollheight;

Comment: Yea, from my experience the body.scrollHeight does not give an accurate number to which you can set the Iframe, (this is speaking for Firefox, but probably others too). I think it depends on how things are done on that page. For instance, in some cases when I adjust the Iframe to the number it gives me, the number will change to a larger number (body height=100%?). Try offsetHeight.

Comment: Hi,I tried in IE with frame.style.height = frame.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight + 50 + 'px'; its workig well. but in firefox its not suppporting so i used   frame.style.height = frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 50 + 'px'; first time its ok.though content I'm removing content every time frame.style.height its keep on increasing. if I examine frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight individually its working well. but if i assign to frame.style its incresing every time. can u pl help me

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are saying that in FF everytime you increase the Iframe, the content reports a bigger number. This is what I was talking about. The way I 'solved' it was to catch the increase and see if it is steady compared to last time, if so, then I ignore it. This may leave you with a scrollbar, so just disable it.